# jquery ui tabs interfering with dynamic content using mod-rewrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, mod-rewrite, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a problem with jquery ui tabs. I have a mod rewrite which rewrites; e.g:

[link1](http://www.example.com/aa.html?uid=bb/123/456) to [link2](http://www.example.com/aa/123/item-title)

The problem is that I have a few jquery ui tabs which prevents the dynamic data from being loaded. I am guessing it's due to the #tabname that is added to the end of the pretty url like so:

[link2](http://www.example.com/aa/123/item-title) to [link3](http://www.example.com/aa/123/item-title#tabname)

How can I get the dynamic data to be loaded in it's correct tab with or without the #tabname in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumptions, based on your description: that this is only a problem when people go to that link with the hash tag directly, like from a bookmark or emailed link; and that you're parsing the url on the client side in order to dynamically load the data.

At the top of your document.ready():

```
$document.ready(function() {
   document.location.hash = "";
   ...
```

This will remove the hash tag. If you needed to use it to go to the right tab, do:

```
$document.ready(function() {
   var tabName = document.location.hash;
   document.location.hash = "";
   // use tabName here to reveal tab
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I might have mis-diagnosed the problem. The hash is not the problem but the [link]<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>[/link] used to switch between tabs which conflicts and blocks the [link]<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>[/link] used for reading the dynamic data from a json api using jquery.

Comment: That's because the full jquerytools already contains jquery, so with both those inculdes, you've got two copies of jquery running. Jquerytools has jquery 1.6.4 in it, and it looks like you're linking to jquery 1.3.0 as well. You could either remove your link to jquery, or instead use a jquerytools that doesn't include jquery, like: http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js

Comment: Also, if you do link to a jquerytools that doesn't include jquery, then I'd recommend linking to a newer version of jquery. 1.3.0 is really old.